# Java String square pattern

Tags: java, string, sequence

A user enters a String and method draws a square.
For example:

- For input= `ram` method draws:
  `r r r`
  `- a -`
  `m m m`
- For input= `code` method draws:
  `c c c c`
  `- o o -`
  `- d d -`
  `e e e e`
- For input = `coder` method draws:
  `c c c c c`
  `- o o o -`
  `- - d - -`
  `- e e e -`
  `r r r r r`

So far I have managed to draw something like this:
`c - - - c`
`- o - o -`
`- - d - -`
`- e - e -`
`r - - - r`

Using this code:

```
static void pattern(String n) {
        int len = n.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                if((i==j)||(i==len-j-1)) {
                    System.out.printf("%c ", n.charAt(i));
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("- ");
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("%n");
        }

    }
```

I have only managed to print diagonally using `if((i==j)||(i==len-j-1))`, but I do not know how I would be able to make it look like example above. How could I upgrade my code to draw the square properly?

Comment: You correctly found boundaries between which you should print your characters, but you take exactly bounds, but skipping everything between them. Any element within these bounds is bigger from left bound and less than right bound. But consider that at the center bounds are switching, so you can try find minimum/maximum bound as left/right bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void pattern(String n) {
        int len = n.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if((i<j)&&(i>len-j-1) || (i>j)&&(i<len-j-1)) {
            System.out.printf("- ");

        } else  {
            System.out.printf("%c ", n.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%n");
}
```

The first condition

```
 (i>j)&&(i<len-j-1)
```

selects the following part

```
x x x x x x x
- x x x x x x
- - x x x x x
- - - x x x x
- - x x x x x
- x x x x x x
x x x x x x x
```

and the

```
 (i>j)&&(i<len-j-1)
```

selects the following parts

```
x x x x x x x
x x x x x x -
x x x x x - -
x x x x - - -
x x x x x - -
x x x x x x -
x x x x x x x
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use double for loop to print 2D array. Just count amount of `-` at the beginning and end of the raw depending on the raw's index.

```
public static void pattern(String str) {
    for (int i = 0, last = str.length() - 1; i <= last; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, dash = last; j <= last; j++, dash--)
            System.out.print(i < j && i > dash || i > j && i < dash ? '-' : str.charAt(i));

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```